# Why a YII blog connects to sqlite well, but not to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have successfully rolled a test blog that supports restful api using Yii 1.1.x, I use ampps in mac, everything works fine when I use SQLite database, I'm able to see all API responses normally, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/) and did some fixes of the source code in that page.

the problem is, when I switched to MYSQL database by

switching from

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString' => '"mysql:host=localhost,dbname=testdrive" Username="root" Password="1234"'),
```

to

```
'db'=>array(
    'connectionString'=>'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test',
    'username'=>'deya',
    'password'=>'',
    //'tablePrefix' => "post",
),
```

in config/main.php

then this error shows up

> Error 500 The table "{{post}}" for active record class "Post" cannot
>   be found in the database.

the database structure is

[image]

if this is usefull, you can find the source code of my test blog [source code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/colppa5oonastt3/yii-blog-rest.zip?dl=0)

Comment: You will have to post the relevevnt code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Also, can you post start of your models/Post.php code here?

**Update:** Please let us know if your issue is resolved. The code seems to be fine. Does the user:deya have access to the DBName 'test' ? Can you login as deya from phpmyadmin without password?

Secondly , make sure DB 'test' has table named 'post' . If so,try using 127.0.0.1 as your host